# Issues with Pacman - keeps failing in the past few months

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, artix-linux

I am having issues updating my Artix (Arch based) Linux.

I use these commands to get the latest mirror list and launch pacman:

```
% sudo pacman -U ./artix-mirrorlist-20221209-1-any.pkg.tar.zst
% sudo mv /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.pacnew /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
% sudo pacman -Sy --needed archlinux-keyring
% sudo pacman -Syyu
```

This always worked successfully in the past, but in the last few months this is the output I get:

```
100  100k  100  100k    0     0   401k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  402k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  471k  100  471k    0     0  1366k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1370k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 40781  100 40781    0     0   188k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  188k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  119k  100  119k    0     0   447k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  449k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 3975k  100 3975k    0     0   803k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--  649k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
....
```

and it keeps going on like that for a long time.

Then this is what I am asked for:

```
100 3040k  100 3040k    0     0  4355k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 4355k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 52477  100 52477    0     0   249k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  251k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  237k  100  237k    0     0   817k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  819k
 Total (   0/1193)                                                                                1969.9 MiB   482 KiB/s 69:44 [----------------------------------------------------------------------------] 100%
(1193/1193) checking keys in keyring                                                                                           [----------------------------------------------------------------------------] 100%
(1193/1193) checking package integrity                                                                                         [----------------------------------------------------------------------------] 100%
error: archlinux-keyring: signature from "Dudemanguy <dudemanguy@artixlinux.org>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/archlinux-keyring-20220927-1.1-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] Y
error: coin: signature from "Alexander F. Rødseth <xyproto@archlinux.org>" is marginal trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/coin-4.0.0.04c190-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] n
error: med-openmpi: signature from "Alexander F. Rødseth <xyproto@archlinux.org>" is marginal trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/med-openmpi-4.1.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] n
error: python-pivy: signature from "Alexander F. Rødseth <xyproto@archlinux.org>" is marginal trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/python-pivy-0.6.8-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] n
error: libreoffice-fresh: signature from "Dudemanguy <dudemanguy@artixlinux.org>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/libreoffice-fresh-7.4.1-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] n
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

I tried giving different answers to those questions, but the result is always the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your keyring is out of date, and without it packages cannot be validated. In general, before upgrading, make sure you get the latest archlinux-keyring first:

```bash
% sudo pacman -Sy --needed archlinux-keyring
% sudo pacman -Su
```

Always run one immediately after the other to avoid partial upgrades.

You can also do this with `pacman-key --refresh-key` as root, but the keyservers tend to be somewhat more error prone than installing the latest `archlinux-keyring` package.

Comment: Switching "arch" with "artix" should work with my distribution...

Comment: @Pietro Please don't put the "arch-linux" tag on non-Arch questions, derivatives of Arch are usually sufficiently different to require different answers, so it's misleading.

Comment: The problem is Artix Linux is in 95th position on DistroWatch, and if I use this as the only tag I may not get any answer at all.

Comment: Worked fine with `artix-keyring`

Comment: I am afraid that with the update I have being trying to do in the past days, the problem reoccurred, even following your indications... There must be something else.